# Impact of adding a 32-Bit ODBC driver to a 64-Bit Win Server 2008 R2

Tags: php, windows-server-2008-r2, odbc, php5

Would there be no problem if i ADD another ODBC driver to a server (a 32bit version to cater my 32bit PHP application) with an existing ODBC 64bit version? Would it not create confilict to other applications? I am worried, that if I install an ODBC 32bit version, it may affect the existing and running applications on the server which maybe using the 64bit ODBC version.

Comment: Why would it cause a conflict.  Only 32-bit applications can use a 32-bit ODBC driver.

Answer (score 0):

The 32-bit and 64-bit software areas are generally kept distinct by the Windows OS.  There are some nuances (which many might call "bugs") to ODBC on 64-bit Windows, which are discussed in [this knowledgebase article](http://wikis.openlinksw.com/UdaWikiWeb/Win32vs64OdbcAdmin) on my employer's documentation site.

The biggest possible issue is if you use User DSNs.  Note that 32-bit applications cannot use 64-bit drivers, and 64-bit applications cannot use 32-bit drivers.  *System* DSNs are kept properly distinct by the MDAC ODBC driver manager -- 32-bit applications are only shown System DSNs based on 32-bit drivers, and 64-bit applications are only shown System DSNs based on 64-bit drivers.  However, *User* DSNs are mixed up -- both 32-bit and 64-bit applications see User DSNs based on both 32-bit and 64-bit drivers.

So -- *if* you use only System DSNs, and name each DSN so it's clear whether that DSN is based on a 32-bit or 64-bit driver, you'll be fine with both 32-bit and 64-bit ODBC drivers installed on the same machine.